# Start a 2010 Reusable Workflow from a 2013 Reusable Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, reusable

This seems to be easily done in a one list scenario with list workflows, as they are meant to run on just **one** list, but what if I want to start a reusable 2010 workflow from a reusable 2013 workflow? The main action (and point) of the 2010 workflow would simply be: 'Create item in Current List' and would be associated with say 3 different libraries. But I want to be able to set the reusable workflow once to start from the 2013 reusable workflow and then it could be run from any of the libraries with which it is associated and create an item in that respective library.

The only option I can see is: Start a **List** workflow. There does not seem to be the option: Start a **Reusable** workflow. Or is the context in which the reusable workflow started not important? Perhaps, since it is reusable, the "Create item in Current List" action would still create items in any of the associated lists?